# Django - Is storing objects in session a good practice?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pickle

```
class Book(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def view(request):
  book = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
  request.session['selected_book'] = book
```

Is it a good practice to store Objects in Session instead of their id ?
Will it be "picklable"   enough to be used in templates for example ?

```
<div>{{ request.session.book.author.name }}</div>
```

Comment: better to store an id in the session. you want to keep all session data as light weight as possible.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. So the answer should be "no it's not a good practice", shouldn't it ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea. Apart from anything else, if you store an object in the session, it won't change if/when the database version does.

Answer (score 4):

there is exception:

```
if your object doesnt exist in db yet
```

for example if you build it (object) through many steps/views.